# sending velocity commands to the robot throught cmd_vel topic

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, linear-velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to send velocity comands to move th bebop drone up and then forward. Here is my code:

```
#include<ros/ros.h>
#include<nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include<geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

float tag_yaw,tag_x,tag_y,tag_z;
ros::Publisher pub;
ros::Subscriber sub;
geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
float err;


 void getpos(const nav_msgs::Odometry& posmsg){

 if (posmsg.pose.pose.position.z<= 1){

 ROS_INFO_STREAM( "Showing position : "
 << "x1 =" << posmsg.pose.pose.position.x
 << "y1 =" << posmsg.pose.pose.position.y
  << "z1 =" << posmsg.pose.pose.position.z);

   msg.linear.x=0.0;
   msg.linear.y=0.0;
   msg.linear.z=  0.1;   // exp ( 0.1);
   msg.angular.x= 0;
   msg.angular.y= 0;
   msg.angular.z=0.0;
    }
    else {

    ROS_INFO_STREAM( "Showing position : "
    << "x =" << posmsg.pose.pose.position.x
    << "y =" << posmsg.pose.pose.position.y
    << "z =" << posmsg.pose.pose.position.z);

     msg.linear.x=0.8*(tag_x-posmsg.pose.pose.position.x);
     msg.linear.y=0.0;
     msg.linear.z=  0.0;   // exp ( 0.1);
     msg.angular.x= 0;
     msg.angular.y= 0;
     msg.angular.z=0.0;
     }

      pub.publish(msg);
     }


   int main(int argc, char **argv){
   ros::init(argc, argv,"velBebop");
   ros::NodeHandle nh;

  tag_x= .5;
  tag_y= 0.0;
   tag_z= 0.0;
   sub = nh.subscribe("/bebop/odom",100, &getpos) ;
    pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/bebop/cmd_vel" ,100);

    ros::spin();
    return 0;
     }
```

I can see that the velocities are being published through the rqt_graph here:
[image: image description]

but the drone is not moving at all! it is not even rotating the helices.
Any suggestion!!!
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331522/sending-velocity-commands-to-the-robot-throught-cmd_vel-topic/) by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-08-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-26**:
The code you show does not appear to initialise the `Publisher` at all. Is that a copy-pasta or actual code?

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2019-08-26**:
@gvdhoorn I forgot that line that I added now. this is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

have you tried to post directly a speed in order to see if the robot accepts the command?

```
rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 10 -- '[0.2, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'
```

Please watch out the drone, I do not know which speeds are proper for you.

**LATER EDIT**

See this git. Sunk has made a wonderful job. I have used his solution, with some modifications at the robot I've work now.

https://github.com/sungjik/my_personal_robotic_companion/blob/master/my_personal_robotic_companion/src/base_controller.cpp

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Ktysai](https://answers.ros.org/users/41908/ktysai/) with karma: 112 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2019-08-26**:
@Ktysai , thanks for your answer, actually it works that way, but how can I manage with the node that publish the commanded velocity, is there anything wrong with the sleep rate or the spining!!!
Please help

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2019-08-27**:
@Ktysai thanks again. Actually I followed the same structure of the code in the link
but the problem is solved by just send an empty message to /bebop/takeoff topic before running the node.
I have another question!!! where to get the battery state so I can send an error message when the battery is low!!!
Please help

**Comment by [Vignesh_93](https://answers.ros.org/users/65377/vignesh_93/) on 2021-03-23**:
Does this solution work for any set point of x, y for the robot. I mean if I want the robot to go to a set point x, y and the odom data is available from the odom topic. Will this above solution work ?

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2021-03-23**:
Well, It worked for me at least.